# How to count mysql rows created by a query in vb net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am using mysql client to connect to my database in vb.net. My problem is how to count the rows when I am using a query string like `"SELECT * FROM table..."` something similar to `mysql_num_rows()` in php? Any ideas? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're pulling into a `DataTable` object, you can simply use `DataTable.Rows.Count` to show the number of rows returned.

EDIT: Since you just want the number of results, the statement should be `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE...` and it should be run using the `SqlCommand` object's `ExecuteScalar()` method. The resulting integer can then be output in the label.

Comment: no i am not pulling them into a DataTable I just want to use the number of rows as a label.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ok my friend i am going to test it and i will answer to you.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`SqlDataReader` has the `RecordsAffected` Property to get count value for affected records, try that.